# "You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of “Share on name.domain.com”."

Tags: permissions, samba

I am having some issues with Samba on my Fedora file share server. I've logged into as the vncuser below on the server itself and I can access the directory, however I get permission denied errors when I try to access it over Samba.

In the `smb.conf` file the following share works:

```
[Admin]
    path = /
    comment = Admin Share (read only)
    read only = true
    directory mask = 0775
    force user = root
    valid users = "Admins"
```

In the `smb.conf` file the following share does not work:

```
[Data]
    path = /mnt/sdb1/share
    comment = Data Share
    read only = no
    directory mask = 0775
    force user = vncuser
    valid users = "Admins"
```

The error I get is a permission denied error:

> You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of
>   “Share on name.domain.com”.

The permissions on the share folder are as follows:

```
drwxrwxr-x. 4 vncuser  vncuser   4096 Sep 23 08:36 share
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or see anything wrong with the configuration? Again the Admin share is working fine its just the Data share that is failing.

Comment: Is the Samba Service Started?

Comment: @eyoung100 Yes, The "Admin" share works fine. The Data share is not working. The Owner / Group for the /mnt/sdb1/share is vncuser as well.

Comment: Can you browse the Data Share as an Admin by browsing to it from `/`(The admin share)?

Comment: Result of `ls -ld /mnt /mnt/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1/share` please.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using SELinux? Does Samba have access to /mnt/sdb1/share? With apps such as SELinux or AppArmor you typically have to grant the app permission to access a particular directory/device as well. They're called "contexts" in SELinux.

You can check using `ls -Z` for example:

```
$ ls -Z /var | grep "log$"
drwxr-xr-x. root root    system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0   log
```